# How do I determine current font style in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context

I want to define a macro that behaves differently within different font families. How do I determine the current font family used in ConTeXt? Is there something like `\f@family` variable?

Comment: Does `\fontalternative` give you the information you are looking for? Or do you want `\fontclass'.

Comment: @Aditya: `\fontalternative` works fine) and how do I use `\fontclass`? can't find any documentation about either of them ...

Comment: @Aditya: yeah, I need more info than `\fontalternative` gives. Something like `ss`, `rm`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConTeXt has two *axis* for font definitions: font styles (serif, sans, and teletype) and alternatives (normal, bold, italic, bolditalic, slanted, boldslanted, and smallcaps). See the [wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching) for details.

The predefined font styles and alternatives are defined in `font-pre.mkiv` using the macros `\definefontstyle` and `\definefontalternative`. The macros `\fontstyle` and `\fontalternative` give the current font style and alternative. So, you can use a combination of these in your tests. For example:

```
\define[1]\Test
    {\NC #1 Sample \NC #1 \fontalternative \NC #1 \fontstyle \NC \NR}
\starttext
\startTABLE[frame=off,offset=0.5em, align=middle]
  \NC   \NC Alternative \NC Style \NC \NR
  \Test{\rm}
  \Test{\it}
  \Test{\sl}
  \Test{\it}
  \Test{\bf}
  \Test{\bi}
  \Test{\ss}
  \Test{\ssit}
  \Test{\sssl}
  \Test{\ssbf}
  \Test{\ssbi}
  \Test{\normal}
  \Test{\italic}
  \Test{\slanted}
  \Test{\bold}
  \Test{\bolditalic}
  \Test{\sans}
  \Test{\sansbold}
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]